# Is it possible to sum records from a column based on records from a different column?

Tags: sql-server

```
JobNo     StepNo  WorkCntr   Hours
10342-63    10    CUTTING    1.95
10390-30    10    CUTTING    2.59
10390-32    10    CUTTING    3.45
10390-34    10    CUTTING    2.55
10390-34    10    CUTTING    1.82
```

So I have this table up above, here's the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderDet.JobNo, OrderDet.StepNo, OrderDet.WorkCntr, OrderDet.Hours
FROM OrderDet;
```

What I'd like to do is to sum the hours if the Job Number is the same and have DISTINCT filter out the duplicate, so ideally, my table should look  like this:

```
JobNo     StepNo  WorkCntr   Hours
10342-63    10    CUTTING    1.95
10390-30    10    CUTTING    2.59
10390-32    10    CUTTING    3.45
10390-34    10    CUTTING    4.37
```

Any way to do this?  Using SQL Server 2012.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic aggregation query using `sum()` and `group by`:

```
select JobNo, StepNo, WorkCntr, sum(Hours) as Hours
from orderDet
group by JobNo, StepNo, WorkCntr
```

Comment: Thank you, that was easier than I thought